# EXEC sproc COALESCE (value1,value2)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to EXEC a stored procedure which requires a COALESCE if a field value is null use another field value.

```
EXEC dbo.TestSproc COALESCE ('Field1','Field2')
```

Would anyone be able to advise on how best to code this?

This will be called in a SQL Job so needs to be one line.

Comment: @Jodrell I don't know how i can break it down much more for you. I need to call a SPROC in a Job' EXEC dbo.TestSproc COALESCE ('EndDate','StartDate') ' My SPROC looks at any activity within 10 days of EndDate if the EndDate is null it needs to use StartDate. I can't edit the stored procedure as it is used in other areas.

Comment: What you've *failed* to put in your question is that your current code *produces an error*. Once you've mentioned that, it's usually also good to *include the actual error message*. (However, in this case I know what the issue is - `EXEC` can accept *literal values* or *variables* for the parameters. It doesn't accept arbitrary *expressions*)

Comment: You could just create another stored procedure that does what you want and call that in the job step.

Answer (score 0):

CASE statement for when that field us NULL

```
    CASE WHEN field IS NULL
    THEN COALESCE ('Field1','Field2')
    ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: can you expand please, i need this as an exec statement for a SQL Job

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
declare @field1 bigint = (select Field1 from table1);
declare @field2 bigint = (select Field2 from table2);
declare @isnull bigint = isnull(@field1, @field2);

exec dbo.TestSproc @isnull
```

Comment: Thanks, although I need this as a single line for a SQL Job

Comment: @shawkins1, well, write that in the question.

Comment: @shawkins1 You can put that all on one line if you need it that way.